# add field and value to array while looping through?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I have the folowing 2 arrays, and I need to add the value of the first one depending on the ID value of the second one as Key so I can order the 2nd array DESC:

$views:

```
Array ( [1851] => 12 [14341] => 7 [17834] => 3 )
```

And I have the folowing array object:

$most_seen_list :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => WP_Post Object ( 
            [ID] => 17834 
            [post_date] => 2021-10-20 16:01:50 
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-10-20 21:01:50 
        )
    [1] => WP_Post Object ( 
            [ID] => 14341 
            [post_date] => 2021-06-01 17:57:00 
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-06-01 22:57:00 
        )
    [2] => WP_Post Object ( 
            [ID] => 1851
            [post_date] => 2021-02-13 18:09:00 
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-02-13 23:09:00 
        )
)
```

with the next foreach Im going through it and I want to change the `[0]..[1]..[3]` key with the value I get from another array:

```
foreach ($most_seen_list as $key => $value) {
    $newResult[$value->ID];
}
```

Expected output:

```
Array ( 
    [12] => WP_Post Object ( 
            [ID] => 1851
            [post_date] => 2021-02-13 18:09:00 
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-02-13 23:09:00 
            )
    [7] => WP_Post Object ( 
            [ID] => 14341 
            [post_date] => 2021-06-01 17:57:00 
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-06-01 22:57:00 
        )
    [3] => WP_Post Object ( 
            [ID] => 17834 
            [post_date] => 2021-10-20 16:01:50 
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-10-20 21:01:50 
        )
)
```

Comment: `$newResult[$value->ID];` doesn't actually _do_ anything. Did you mean to assign the value? e.g. `$newResult[$value->ID] = $key;` perhaps...

Comment: Does it matter if resulting array get's rearanged?
If not, you could use ksort on $newResult and $views and array_combine($views, $newResult)

Comment: If you do not need the views as keys per se, but just need the data linked to the WP_Post, you could also use \SplObjectStorage to attach each view count to the object
$viewInfo = new SplObjectStorage();
foreach ($most_seen_list as $key => $post) {
    $viewInfo->attach($post, $views[$post->ID] ?? null);
}
```
Now you can use $viewInfo[$oneOfThePosts] to get the views

Comment: Do you need to know the amount of views after you sorted the array of posts? Otherwise you could use usort with a callback that knows about the $views and sorts accordingly. What is the PHP version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already sorted the `$views` array. So you will need to process each of the array of `$most_seen_list` objects to find the right one using an inner loop

```
$views = Array ( 1851 => 12, 14341 => 7, 17834 => 3 );
$most_seen_list = Array ( 
    (Object) [ 'ID' => 17834,'post_date' => '2021-10-20 16:01:50', 'post_date_gmt' => '2021-10-20 21:01:50',
    ],
    (Object) [ 'ID' => 14341, 'post_date' => '2021-06-01 17:57:00', 'post_date_gmt' => '2021-06-01 22:57:00'
    ],
    (Object) ['ID' => 1851, 'post_date' => '2021-02-13 18:09:00', 'post_date_gmt' => '2021-02-13 23:09:00' 
    ]
);

$new = [];
//get the ID'2 in the predefined order set in $views
foreach ( $views as $key=>$val) {
    // for each view find the correct object in $most_seen_list
    foreach( $most_seen_list as $obj) {
        if ( $obj->ID == $key ) {
            $new[$val] = $obj;
            break;  // terminate this iteration
        }
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1851
            [post_date] => 2021-02-13 18:09:00
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-02-13 23:09:00
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 14341
            [post_date] => 2021-06-01 17:57:00
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-06-01 22:57:00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 17834
            [post_date] => 2021-10-20 16:01:50
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-10-20 21:01:50
        )

)
```

Comment: Still it can be problematic when there are posts with the same amount of views

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the view amount as keys (which can be problematic if some view amounts are the same anyway) you could use the following to just sort the posts in the correct order.

```php
// sort asc on views
usort($most_seen_list, function($postA, $postB) use ($views) {
    return $views[$postA->ID] <=> $views[$postB->ID];
});
$most_seen_list = array_reverse($most_seen_list); // reverse the order, so most viewed is first
```

After this you can still get the views per post using:

```php
$views[$oneOfThePosts->ID];
```